# How can I retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database in two different activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up an android apps that could show the personal data in two different activity. The data is stored in my firebase database, can anyone help me doing that?

I already tried to use addValueEventListener in both of my java classes. User's  class that is responsible to display user information in User Profile activity is successfully retrieved the data from my firebase, but the other one still couldn't retrieve the data from my firebase.
This is the code from java class that couldn't retrieve the data from my firebase.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_land_profile);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mDBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    nama_lahan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_lahan);
    lebar_lahan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lebar_lahan);
    panjang_lahan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.panjang_lahan);
    luas_lahan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.luas_lahan);
    jenis_lahan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jenis_lahan);
    jenis_pupuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jenis_pupuk);
    public void fetchLandData (String userUID){
    mAkun = mDBase.getReference("Akun").child(userUID);
    mAkun.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot landData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Lahan lahan = landData.getValue(Lahan.class);

                if(lahan != null){
                    namaLahan = lahan.getNamaLahan();
                    jns_lahan = lahan.getJenisLahan();
                    jns_pupuk = lahan.getJenisPupuk();
                    lebarLahan = lahan.getLebarLahan();
                    panjangLahan = lahan.getPanjangLahan();

                    luasLahan = panjangLahan*lebarLahan;

                    nama_lahan.setText(namaLahan);
                    jenis_pupuk.setText(jns_pupuk);
                    jenis_lahan.setText(jns_lahan);
                    lebar_lahan.setText(String.valueOf(lebarLahan));
                    panjang_lahan.setText(String.valueOf(panjangLahan));
                    luas_lahan.setText(String.valueOf(luasLahan));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LandProfileActivity.this, "Gak iso pisan ``bos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

While the other one is pretty much the same structure but different variable name and it could give me the result that i wanted.

[That is the screenshot from my application that failed to retrieve data from my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iAVh.png) and
[This is what my Firebase DB looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOMjS.png)

These are some error that i copied from my logcat :

`2019-02-09 23:32:11.070 1645-3271/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.johno.test/com.example.johno.test.LandProfileActivity/1
2019-02-09 23:32:11.072 1645-3271/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.johno.test/com.example.johno.test.LandProfileActivity/1
2019-02-09 23:32:11.079 1645-3065/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.johno.test/com.example.johno.test.LandProfileActivity/1`

Comment: It's unclear what isn't working about your code at this point, so you will have to do some legwork to add more information. The first thing is to not ignore errors, but instead add implement `onCancelled`: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. The second is to see if that throws an error. If it doesn't: place a breakpoint on the first line inside of `onDataChange`, and see if that ever gets hit. If it does, step through the method and check each value to see what line doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for replying,and sorry if my question making you confused, but what i'm trying to do is retrieving data from my firebase db. My db contains root/Akun/UID/User and root/Akun/UID/Lahan. The activity that retrive User data works very well, but the other one that retrieve Lahan doesn't work and just giving me blank output like the screenshot and codeblock that i specify earlier in my question. Hope that explain you a lot better. Thanks again.

Comment: Your question was clear enough, but we can't run your code for you. Only you can do that, and then tell us what happens for each line. Please take the steps in my comment and update your question with what happens when you execute them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that thing kept coming in my logcat when i run my code

Answer (score 0):

you can put Firebase ValueEvent listener in Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   //mAkun field declaration;
   private ValueEventListener value_event_listener;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mAkun = mDBase.getReference("Akun").child(userUID);
        mAkun.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {/*..*/}
    }
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        mAkun.removeEventListener(value_event_listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i think i don't know what you meant about that? Can you explain more about it? I already commented my question if you need more explanation. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a very good idea, and possibly costly, as the app will be constantly listening for changes and causing download charges for each change, even if they're not needed.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for adding, can you explain more to me? I already edited my question above. Thank you